# ANTLR netbeans config Could not find or load main class org.antlr.Tool

Tags: netbeans, antlr, antlr3, antlr4, netbeans-plugins

I tried to configure antlr and netbeans with build xml, i followed the http://wiki.netbeans.org/AntlrInNetBeansJavaApplication
tutorial, but when i clean and build the project i get an error like

Error: Could not find or load main class org.antlr.Tool

I set the classpath: SET CLASSPATH=.;c:\Users\BayDebrecen\Downloads\antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%

my build xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Builds, tests, and runs the project MyAntlrProject.

```
<target name="-pre-compile" depends="antlr">
</target>

<target name="init-antlr">
    <!-- Full path to Antlr jar -->
    <property name="antlr.jar" location="c:\\Users\\BayDebrecen\\Downloads\\antlr-4.2-complete.jar"/>
    <!-- Grammar path -->
    <property name="antlr.grammar" location="src\\myantlrproject\\MyGrammar.g"/>
</target>

<target name="antlr" depends="init-antlr" unless="up-to-date">
    <!-- Compiling grammar -->
    <java classname="org.antlr.Tool"  fork="true">
        <arg value="${antlr.grammar}"/>
        <classpath path="${antlr.jar}"/>
    </java>        
</target>
```

How can I correctly compile and run my generated class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ANTLR3's `Tool` was in the package `org.antlr`, but with ANTLR4, it is in the package `org.antlr.v4`.

So, change:

```
classname="org.antlr.Tool"
```

into:

```
classname="org.antlr.v4.Tool"
```

Comment: Big up. Thanks a lot. I spent the whole day with this. :)